# close() system call not removes descriptor from /proc/pid/fdinfo

Tags: linux-kernel

Im using fanotify to track disk changes.
fanotify associates file descriptor to my process, which I need to close once Im done dealing with the event.
However, even though the close(fd) is successful, It seems that the file descriptor remains open.
Im using the [man fanotify example](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html#example)

The `close(..)` returns with no errors, but looking at `/proc/<pid>/fdinfo` tells a different story.
Is there a way to overcome this?
Without clearing the descriptors associated with a process, a `read(..)` call may encounter `read: Too many open files`

The error Im receiving is:
`EMFILE The per-process limit on the number of open files has been reached.  See the description of RLIMIT_NOFILE in getrlimit(2).`

I expected to test it with this sample code, but here it works OK:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
int main ()
{
    close(2);

    std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could not reproduce. How are you compiling it? Which OS? Which kernel version? And use `cstdio` instead of `stdio.h` when using C++.

Comment: Thats the point. Its not working only on the descriptors that fanotify receives. this sample code works as one would expect. Ubuntu 15.04, 3.19.0-33

Comment: With the example from the manpage, as before, could not reproduce on 14.04, 3.13.0-65 or Arch Linux, 4.2.5-1. A total of 4 fds (including the standard ones) are the only ones opened by the program/

Comment: You can raise the limit of open files often, and nowadays it it not that low...have you tried fclose? Are you sure that upon using the libraries, they do not detect it is close and open it out again?

Comment: @muru Just to make sure, Did you make some disk activity, so that some events come up?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I wouldnt want that, because it wont solve my real problem, only hide it. as much as I understand, open() was used to get this handle, therefore I must use `close()` and not `fclose()`

Comment: @buddy123 Oh, plenty. I ran it on my root filesystem, while using byobu. And `byobu` was constantly checking configuration files, et.c, to update the status bar. Many events/sec.

Comment: @muru Thanks, I'll try a different distro.

Comment: Post actual code **that exhibits the problem**. Posting code that doesn't exhibit the problem is useless.